# How to make a submit_tag look like a link in rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to make a submit tag in rails to look like a link ?

`<%= submit_tag :save %>`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Save</a>
```

Comment: How about using CSS. Thats why you have CSS, to make stuff look the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using jquery you can do like this

```
<%= link_to 'Save', "#", :onclick=>"$('.form_class').submit()" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
<%= submit_tag :save do %><a href="javascript:void(0)">Save</a><%end%>
```